# sed pattern replace with new line

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace with insert in all files in the directory with the following command:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak ':begin;$!N;s/\(@Autowired\)\n\(public .*\)\((ServletRequest\)/\2() \{\}\n&/;tbegin' {} \;
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

Match:

```
@Autowired
public something(ServletRequest
```

Replace With:

```
public something() {}
@Autowired
public something(ServletRequest
```

I am basically trying to add a default constructor to all my java classes in a certain directory/package.  I can't seem to match the newline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
sed '/@Autowired/{:l
    N;s/\(.*public[ ]*\)\([^(]*\)\((ServletRequest\)/public \2() {}\n\1\3/;
    /ServletRequest/!bl}' input
```

and if you have the ServletRequest bit always following the @autowired:

```
sed '/@Autowired/{
   N;s/\(.*public[ ]*\)\([^(]*\)\((ServletRequest\)/public \2() { }\n\1\3/}' 
  input
```

Comment: getting an "unknown option `s`" for your command, something missing?

Comment: second command doesn't produce an error but is missing the method name  when replacing: public something() {}
@Autowired
public *missing*(ServletRequest